# openlayers dynamic image sizes

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I have the bellow code:

```
const extent = [0, 0, 1000, 100];
new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        url: this.config.settings.staticImageURL,
        projection: new ol.proj.Projection({
          code: "xkcd-image",
          units: "pixels",
          extent: extent,
        }),
        imageExtent: extent,
      }),
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
        wrapX: true,
      })
    }),
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    resolution: 1,
    center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
  }),
});
```

Btw, this code is a very simplified version of actual code.
This is inside a JavaScript class, I use it as a component that I can give a config, and it creates an openLayers instance for me. I reuse it multiple times across the application, and the image url is dynamically given to this component.
What this does, is basically it get's an image url, and puts it inside an openLayers instance for some functionality which does not matter here. But I don't know anything about the image (it's sizes), before runtime.

**The problem is**, the `extent`. I HAVE TO KNOW the **size** of the image and set the extent accordingly. If image is for example 1000 x 100, I'll have to set the extent to `[0,0,1000,100]` but then again if I hard code it, another image might be for example 786 x 600 and because I have hard coded the extent the image's height will be too thin.

**What I want, is**, I want to have the image inside the openlayers, and keep the image's aspect ratio, no matter what image, with whatever size I have.

*Openlayers version 6*

Comment: I ended up, calculating the sizes in the backend, and sending them beside the image path for frontend use.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to load the image to get its size.  If you have multiple layers it would be easier to use a function which immediately creates the layer which can be added to the map and asynchronously sets its source when the image size is known

```
function dynamicLayer (url) {
  const imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image();
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.onload = function() {
    const extent = [0, 0, img.width, img.height];
    imageLayer.setSource(
      new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        url: url,
        projection: new ol.proj.Projection({
          code: "xkcd-image" + url,
          units: "pixels",
          extent: extent,
        }),
        imageExtent: extent,
      }),
    );
  };
  img.src = url;
  return imageLayer;
}
```